# How to instantiate a Google API service using google-auth?

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api, google-authentication

I'm trying to populate a Google sheet from a Python program using its API, using the quickstart guide (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) as a starting point:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file as oauth_file, client, tools

# Setup the Sheets API
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'
store = oauth_file.Storage('token.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('sheets', 'v4', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
```

However, I was only able to get this to work using the `flow_from_clientsecrets()` method, which (by default) opens an authentication page in the browser. This does not seem suitable for something I'd like to run periodically on a production server.

In any case, according to https://pypi.org/project/oauth2client/, `oauth2client` is deprecated and developers are recommended to use [`google-auth`](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) instead.

Therefore, I tried to adapt this example as follows (following https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#service-account-private-key-files):

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    'google_client_secret.json')
```

Where `'google_client_secret.json'` is the JSON file downloaded from the API console, which looks like this (scrambled and pretty-printed):

```
{
  "installed": {
    "client_id": "33e.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "project_id": "nps-survey-1532981793379",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_secret": "foobar",
    "redirect_uris": [
      "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob",
      "http://localhost"
    ]
  }
}
```

When I run the script, however, I get the following error:

```
(lucy-web-CVxkrCFK) bash-3.2$ python nps.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nps.py", line 25, in <module>
    'google_client_secret.json')
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/oauth2/service_account.py", line 209, in from_service_account_file
    filename, require=['client_email', 'token_uri'])
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/_service_account_info.py", line 73, in from_filename
    return data, from_dict(data, require=require)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/_service_account_info.py", line 51, in from_dict
    'fields {}.'.format(', '.join(missing)))
ValueError: Service account info was not in the expected format, missing fields token_uri, client_email.
```

From dropping into the debugger, I noticed that the problem is basically that the dictionary passed into the `from_dict()` method is the *entire* dictionary in the `google_client_secret.json` file, which has only one key, `"installed"`. What the `from_dict()` method seems to be 'looking for' is the sub-dictionary, as this contains a `token_uri` key, although even this doesn't contain the required `client_email` key.

What I'm suspecting is that I've created the wrong type of OAuth2 client for my use case, because the JSON containing the client secrets isn't in the expected format. Any ideas how I could fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth, there are three types of client IDs:

1. Web application client IDs
2. Installed application client IDs
3. Service Account client IDs

My use case is a [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount), and upon creating one and choosing the *Furnish a new private key* option, I found that I obtained a JSON file which does match the expected format. (The one I had was for an installed application).

Comment: @tehhowch, I assume you mean I should carry out point 2: accept the answer? StackOverflow only allows you to accept your own answer after a certain period elapses; in my case, I can only accept it tomorrow. I'll do it then.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the json file, but not from the credentials page.

Go to:

1. https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts (select a project first)
2. Pick or create a service account from the list
3. Click the 3 dots and choose "manage keys"
4. "Add key" > "Create new key", and you'll be able to download the correct json here.